# Groups of Feeders and Requests in Gatling Scenario

Tags: scala, gatling

I have different Requests that I test separately with this pattern:

```
feed(feeder)
      .exec(
        firstRequest,
        secondRequest
      )
```

Now I have a Test that needs first another one with the same pattern:

test1 > test2

To achieve this I made a case class and initiated it like this:

```
case class FilCall(startMsg: String, testData: Seq[TestData])

def setupScenario(filCalls: FilCall*): SetUp = {

  lazy val filCallTests = filCalls.map { filCall =>
    val feeder: Seq[Map[String, Any]] =
      filCall.testData.map(oneFeed) // create one Feeder

    group(filCall.startMsg) {
      feed(feeder.iterator)
        .exec(
          start(filCall.startMsg),
          checkResult(..)
        )
     }
   }


   def scn = scenario(getClass.getSimpleName)
     .exec(getToken)
     .exec(filCallTests: _*)


   setUp(scn.inject(withUsers(filCalls.size)))
     .protocols(http)
}
```

This works with one `FilCall`, but throws with more than one:

```
17:58:57.338 [ERROR] i.g.a.Gatling$ - Run crashed
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Feeder is now empty, stopping engine
    at io.gatling.core.action.SingletonFeed$$anonfun$receive$1.applyOrElse(SingletonFeed.scala:67)
```

Is this scenario with Groups possible? How is it done.

Answer (score 1):

This is the expected error when you use a feeder instance with the default queue strategy where records can only be used once, and you're trying to pull more records than it contains, see [doc](https://gatling.io/docs/current/session/feeder/#strategies).

Comment: Thanks, but I create more than one Feeder, Does this mean that you can have only one  Feeder in a scenario?

Comment: No. It means that each feeder needs to contain at least as many records as you'll be trying to pull from it.

Comment: Do you have an example on how to use more than one Feeder? As mentioned - it works with one - but as soon I have more than one I have the problem.

Comment: You're not listening. I'm telling you to add more records in your feeder.